# Struts2 Validation for Wildcard methods

Tags: java, struts2

I have a situation where i have 2 methods in the same action class, method1 and method2. Below is my action mappings in struts.xml

```
  < action name="actionName_*" class="sample.input.SubmitTest" method="{1}">
   < interceptor-ref name="defaultStak" />  
   < result name="input">info.jsp< result ends>
   < result name="success">info.jsp< result ends>
   < result name="error">error.jsp< result ends>
  < action ends>
```

Validation rules for method1 and method2 are different so i have 2 validation xml files. 1: actionName_method1-validation.xml
2: actionName_method2-validation.xml

This configuration is as per http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-DynamicMethodInvocation

I invoke these methods from a JSP as shown below,

```
< s:form action="actionName_" method="post">
    <!-- here goes the fields to be submitted -->
    <s:submit type="simple" method="method1" value="execute1"/>
    <s:submit type="simple" method="method2" value="execute2"/>
< s:form  end tag>
```

However for some reason the validations are not getting executed. Am I missing something here, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in the s:submit, below is the correct s:submit which worked

```
< s:form action="actionName_" method="post">
    < s:submit type="simple" action="actionName_method1" value="execute1"/>
    < s:submit type="simple" action="actionName_method2" value="execute2"/>
< s:form  end tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this question, but the one that appeared here wasn't solving my problem.

To solve the problem, you have to apply the @Rajesh solution (use `action` attributes instead of `method` in the `<s:submit>` tag) **and** you have to **rename the validation file** so that it fulfills the following rule:

```
<actionClass>-<actionAlias>-validation.xml
```

So the validation files, in this case, should be renamed to:

```
SubmitTest-actionName_method1-validation.xml
SubmitTest-actionName_method2-validation.xml
```

as the action class is SubmitTest.

I hope this answer can help others with the problem of XML validation with wildcard methods.